# How to set value of a slider element with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm in the middle of an RPA project where I need to upload files to a platform (not my site) and then need to adjust the slider to a certain value.

[image]

Now in order to automate this, there is the option for me to use a "Javascript Function", which I intend to use eventually. However, to solve this problem I first need to be able to execute the correct code in the browser console.

Here's the code:

```
<span class="MuiSlider-root jss1 MuiSlider-colorPrimary">
    <span class="MuiSlider-rail jss6"></span>
    <span class="MuiSlider-track jss5" style="left: 0%; width: 24.2424%;"></span>
    <input value="0.25" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" winautomationoriginalcolor="rgb(255, 255, 255)" type="hidden">
        <span class="MuiSlider-thumb jss2 MuiSlider-thumbColorPrimary jss26 jss25" tabindex="0" role="slider" style="left: 24.2424%;" data-index="0" aria-orientation="horizontal" aria-valuemax="1" aria-valuemin="0.01" aria-valuenow="0.25">
            <span class="jss27 MuiSlider-valueLabel jss4">
                <span class="jss28">
                    <span class="jss29">25%</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </input>
</span>
```

I've tried various simple Javascript approaches like `document.querySelector("input[type='range']");`

However, I now found out that this uses jQuery, which I have no knowledge of.

So I was thinking someone could show me the code of how I can set the "input value" and thus move the slider. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jquery for this. `document.querySelector` is plain js. Try using classnames like `document.querySelector('.MuiSlider-rail')`.

Note that special characters need to be scaped. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Thanks @Eduardo Robles! However, do you know what to put into the console in order for it to work? I've tried you suggestion in order to change the value, like these for example:

document.getElementsByClassName('.MuiSlider-rail').value = 15;

document.getElementsByClassName('.MuiSlider-thumb jss2 MuiSlider-thumbColorPrimary jss26 jss25').value = 15;

document.getElementsByClassName('.MuiSlider-track jss5').value = 15;


Didn't work for me though.

Comment: Edit: Actually it does change the value, but the slider doesn't change at all so nothing happens..

Answer (score 0):

As per your initial issue, if you only want the slider to be at 25%, then use `value="25"`, no need for a decimal there... 
To set the value of any input type using `JavaScript` all you need to do is reference the value attribute using JavaScript, no JQuery needed. You can use many methods of selector methods. In my example, I use `getElementById()` and reference the `id` to target the `element` and then use `.value` to set the value. I use an event listener as an example for `mouseenter` and `mouseout` as that is easy to show the value being modified.

```js
let range = document.getElementById('rangeElement');
range.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
  range.value = '100';
})
range.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
  range.value = '50';
})
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="rangeElement">
```

***Reference by class:***

```js
let range = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');
let button = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
// using an event listener on the button and listening for a click
// when clicked, the value for the range slider will be set to '90'
// reference the key of the element/s as the selector method used could have more than one element.
button[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  range[0].value = 90;
})
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="rangeElement">
<button>Press me</button>
```

***By tag name:***

```js
// input set to a value of '50' in HTML
let range = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
// with a selector method that can select more than one element you must reference the 
// elements key value, in this case there is only one input tag, so we reference the first key
// which is 0
range[0].value = 15;
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="rangeElement">
```

Comment: Thanks @dale landry!

So is it correct that in order to change the value on a slider of a foreign page I could us e something like this:

let range = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');
range[0].value = 90;

Because I tried that while using it in the console and unless I'm missing something that didn't work..

Comment: If your element is only the one element use document.getElementById, then no keys are needed -> if you are getting the element whos selector is a multiple element selector, like `getElementsByClassName()` then you must select the key for the specific element, but if you use a single selector like `getElementById()` you will only have to reference the id's value. `change the value on a slider of a foreign page` -> are you trying to change the value on another page?

Comment: Also make sure your `value` attribute is set to the proper value... `value="0.25"` Should be `value="25"`

Comment: Lastly test your output in the console for the selector. Do a console.log on the element and make sure you are returning the elements properties in the log. Then you know your selector is working properly and you will be able to access the `value` attributes property/value...

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to manipulate a slider on another page (one that isn't mine).
I managed to change the value with your tips. However, the slider doesn't update to the new value, and as soon as I click anywhere on the page the value skips back to the initial one (before the change). So I'm thinking I might need to "update" the page or HTML after changing the value as you suggested. Is that right?